# Split string into array by regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need to create an array by searching a string for occurrences of '[' followed by 0 or more characters followed by ']'.

My test string:

```
$string="[item 1] [2] [] [item3]";
```

All of the above must be matched.

I think the regex to do so is

```
\[*\]
```

But how do I create an array out of the string? Do I use

```
preg_match_all("\[*\]", $string, $matches);
```

?

Comment: FYI, "split" isn't the right word for what you're doing; check out the docs for `preg_split()` to see what it does.  This is the inverse of a split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/\[.*?\]/', $string, $matches);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('/\[[^\[\]]*\]/', $string, $matches);
```

The first one stops matching as soon as it sees a closing bracket, but it will match an opening bracket if it sees one first. That is, it would match `"[ [foo]"` if it's present in the input.

The second one is more robust because will only find properly balanced square brackets; ie, they can't contain square brackets.  If brackets can be nested, neither regex will work; that's a much more complicated problem.

Comment: Why are there double quotes and then single quotes surrounding the expression?

Comment: That was a typo; I was replacing the doubles with singles but I got distracted.  In general, you should prefer single quotes so you don't have to worry about escaping backslashes.  Of course, if you're taking advantage of variable interpolation, you have to use double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Close:

```
preg_match_all("!\[.*?\]!", $string, $matches);
```

and then `$matches[0]` will contain the strings.

Three changes were made:

1. Wrapped expression in ! (you can use / or whatever);
2. It's .* not * (in your example [* is saying "0 or more ["); and
3. It was made non-greedy with .*?. If you don't then you will get only one match containing basically the whole string. Take a look at [Finer points of PHP regular expressions](http://www.skdevelopment.com/php-regular-expressions.php).

Comment: @Joseph: It's called the delimiter, normally it's \ but you may want to use something that's not regulary in the subject string, otherwise you'll have to escape it. For me, ~ works.

Comment: Yes I generally use ! instead of / because / often appears in the search pattern (or at least it does for me) but ! rarely does. Others use different things (eg eyze uses ~).

Answer (score 0):

Try preg_split()

Comment: Why do you think `preg_split()` would work better than `preg_match_all()`?  (It's a trick question; ignore the title and read the question again.)